# How can I focus Terminator (a terminal emulator) with a key from anywhere?

Tags: shortcut-keys, terminator

I'm currently using Guake on my main monitor, which has a very nifty feature of allowing you to press a key at any time to show and focus the terminal.  I'm running Terminator on a second monitor, and I'd like to get similar functionality with another key.

I've searched its preferences and can't find such a function, is there another way to accomplish this?  I'd like to be able to press a certain key combo anywhere to focus/un-focus Terminator.

Comment: Ah. Terminator has an option to have a key hide and unhide the window, but it doesn't focus right. The first time I unhide the  window, it doesn't get focus, and I have to hide and unhide again to get focus. :(